# adding an array of data to a dropdown list from multiple databases

Tags: c#, ms-access, database-connection

I have an interesting question I believe. I am writing an application that does a search in C:\ for folders that follow the same naming convention. When a folder is located the application needs to go into the database within the folder and pull one bit of data. that data should be added to a list-box, or drop-down. Below is what I have so far, and it properly grabs one folder....but not all the folders with the same naming convention. I believe it's the

```
profselect.Text = reader[0].ToString();
```

line but not sure.

the Goal is, I have 4 different folders with names like Rameses-100, Rameses-101, and so on. Each folder contains it's own Ramdata.mdb. and in that MDB is a name that I would like to be listed in the profselect drop-down box. further down the road the user will be able to switch to the selected data-set using the name listed in the box. Currently if I run this it just puts one of the folders ramdata info in the box. I would like to have more then one.

```
string directory = @"C:\";
        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory, "Rameses-*");
        foreach (string foldername in folders)
        {
            var myDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
            using (var conection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source="+foldername+"\\Program\\Ramdata.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****"))
            {
                conection.Open();
                var query = "Select u_company From t_user";
                var command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conection);
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();                    
                while (reader.Read())
                    profselect.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                conection.Close();
            }
```

Comment: OK, then what ?? do you want to add the result to a dropDown,
or is there some errors? your question is not clear enough.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, the string (in this case the result of the query) should be put into the profselect dropdown box. I edited the code above with the full snippet.

Comment: You haven't asked a question, so what you are doing currently is asking someone to develop your application for you.

Comment: I didn't think so, I guess I was asking is there something I was doing wrong to achieve the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough, However lets say that the code above is working.

You want to add the result every time you preforms this operation (I assume).
again assuming you're using windows forms.
put a comboBox on your form.

then when preforming the operation you need to keep a list of what you got before then use it as dataSource for the comboBox.
The code below demonstrate this:

```
 List<string> dataList = new List<string>(); // this line is global not inside a closed scoop
 var myDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
 using (var conection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source="+foldername+"\\Program\\Ramdata.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****"))
 {
    conection.Open();
    var query = "Select u_company From t_user";
    var command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, conection);
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();                    
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       profselect.Text = reader[0].ToString(); 
       dataList.Add(profselect.Text);
    }
 }
 myComboBox.DataSource = dataList;
 myComboBox.SelectedText = dataList.Last();
```

that as far as I can help with this much information you gave.

Comment: so I guess I wasn't keeping a running tally of the results and instead just tried to write them directly to the drop down box. I am sorry my question wasn't any clearer, it's tricky to explain exactly what I am doing with it, it's like a profile changer, each folder contains a profile for a user, and that info is stored in the t_user  field. originally the drop down box just listed the names of the folders which works ok for some to read but not others. It is easier to select by names. I thought getting the name in that field and listing that instead of just the folder name would be easier

Comment: @ShaneSuperflyMacNeill Ok I understand, I think I covered what you need in my answer, I hope this helped.

Comment: but again you need to tell what platform are you working on, is it winForms? Access forms? wpf?

Comment: sorry, winforms, VS 2012. the above code seemed to work ok. It shows my 2 test folders and the names in the database, but clears the first one on dropdown. Thank You, I can attempt to remedy that.